# Python Profiler garbage

Tags: python, profiling

I am currently profiling some python code like so:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.runctx('self._Foo ()', globals(), locals(), 'c:/restats.txt')

def Foo(self):
    stuff
```

The code runs successfuly, outputs no exception. However my restats.txt looks like this:

`SomeFunc(   i   i   gÇZ3a/­?gÇZ3a/­?0(   s;   C:\SomeFolder\bar.pyiL   t`

Basically it is 150 lines of garbage characters with random paths and function names mixed in.

What could be the issue? Am I using this correctly? The python file is being loaded in through Maya if that makes a differance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is not meant to be human-readable.  As described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html), you can use the `pstats` module to load the file and explore the profiling data.

Comment: That will teach me to skim the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation for what to do *after* you have collected the trace information. I believe you will need to use [`pstats.Stats`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats) to extract the information you need.